# How do I prevent Ajax.BeginForm from loading a new page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have an Ajax form with a single input and a button.  On submit, the form should only post the entered value to an action method.  My form is correctly posting to the User controller's Log method but when done, the page redirects to /User/Log.

How can I avoid this?

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Log", "User", null, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{%>
    Please enter the username: 
    <%= Html.TextBox("Username", "")%>
    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

Here is the action method:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void ForgotPassword(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string username = collection["Username"];

        //TODO:  some work
    }
}
```

Thanks,
-Keith

Comment: Hello Keith, Did you found any answer for this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this adding a new { target = "_self" } as htmlAttributes object worked for me as in

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Log", "User", null, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { target = "_self" }))
{%>
```